# How to make a movie in Igor with one graph of multiple traces

Tags: igor

I am running a program on Igor and I'd like to create a function that makes a movie of the traces graphed in a sequential manner. The program generates a table of waves that swaps between x and y axes such as,

| Point | Time0 | Data0 | Time1 | Data1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5.3860002 | 14518253 | 5.3829999 | 15511268 |
| 2 | 5.4910002 | 13881730 | 5.487 | 15299764 |

The program allows me to create this graph/Table for as many waves as I have. Currently, I make a movie by calling

```
'''
NewMovie
AddMovie Frame
//Make a new graph
AddMovie Frame
//Make a new graph
AddMovie Frame
//Make a new graph
//etc etc
CloseMovie
'''
```

This is obviously very tedious, so I am trying to make it so I can just make one graph/table with many waves, then update a new graph with each wave and loop the NewMovie until it's complete.

The following code was made for something similar, but I cannot make it work for a double float dataset, which is what I have - not a matrix. I also cannot figure out how to call the waves in the way that the table above shows (i.e., every other). Any help or tips are appeciated.
'''

```
Function MakeMovie(matrix,xWave)
Wave matrix,xWave
variable i //loop variable
//make a dummy wave to accept individual rows
Make/O/N=(dimsize(matrix,1)) framewave
//create the first frame of the movie in a Graph windows called "FrameGraph"
Display/N=FrameGraph framewave vs xWave
Label/W=FrameGraph left "Intensity (a.u.)"
Label/W=FrameGraph bottom "Wavelength (nm)"
WaveStats/Q matrix //Get statistics of matrix
//set axis to a constant to prevent autoscaling
SetAxis left V_min,1.1*V_max
//Name the movie after the original wave
String movieName = NameofWave(matrix) + ".mov"
//create a new movie with the original wave's name
NewMovie /F=30/L/I/O as movieName
//start loop to add frames to movie
for (i = 0; i < dimsize(matrix,0);i += 1)
framewave=matrix[i][p] //advance to the next trace in the sequence
DoUpdate //update the graph with the next trace in the sequence
AddMovieFrame //add a frame to the movie
endfor
CloseMovie //Close the movie file and save it to disk.
Killwindow FrameGraph //clean up
Killwaves framewave //clean up
End
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Please wrap your code in code tags and indent it for readability. Igor Pro does that with selecting the code and choosing Edit->Adjust Indentation.

Regarding your question. The following works here:

```
Make/O/N=(75, 100) matrix = p + q
Make/O/N=(100) xwave = 0.1 * p
MakeMovie(matrix, xWave)
```

The row dimension in matrix gives the number of frames where as the columns holds the data for each trace.